# mongoose object not saving properly after pushing an object to an array property

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack

my user schema includes a notifications property, its value is an array of object (each object being a notification)

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //a bunch of other user properties.
    notifications: [{
        notification: String,
        directLink: String,
        notificationType: Number, //0=vote, 1=comment, 2= answer, 3=post from watched user, 4=watch
        onObject: { //not necessary if type (above) is 4
            type: String, //post, comment, answer
            id: String //id. but not as mongoose object because it is not necessary in this case.
        },
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true},
        newNotification: {type: Boolean, default: true}
    }]
});
```

my problem is when im trying to add a new notification. When somebody posts something new, or somebody replies to your comment, etc. a function called newNotification is called, and the user to be notified is passed into this function as an argument, in the form of post.author (post is a mongoose object with author as one of its properties with the value being the ObjectId of a user, its populated before being passed into the function).

inside the new notifications function, the object is prepared and then pushed to the user.notifications array:

```
var newNot = {
            notification: notification,
            directLink: directLink,
            notificationType: action[0],
            onObject: on
        }
//this code is at the end of the function, newNot now contains the data for the new notification.
//the user is passed in as "notifyUser"
console.log(">>>>>>>>"+notifyUser);
console.log(">>>>>>>>>"+notifyUser.notifications);
notifyUser.notifications.push(newNot);                       
console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>"+notifyUser.notifications);
console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+notifyUser);
notifyUser.save();
```

the problem is that the notification is not saved. it works properly, its added as a notification to the user. the properties of it that are set by default are even added properly. but it does not save
the general method works perfectly on another user property that's just a number that increases, so that can't be the problem. but i still tried to query the database for the user then run this stuff in the callback, but the changes still aren't saved. I've spent hours trying to figure out why its not being saved properly, but got to absolutely nothing.

notes: no, it would not be better to make a notifications schema, in this specific case, it's unnecessary.

Comment: You could use update query while inserting into that `notification` array.

here is the documentation link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty so would it be used like User.update({_id: notifyUser._id}, {$push: {notifications: newNot}}); ?

Comment: yes, `User.update({_id: notifyUser._id}, {$push: {notifications: newNot}}).exec();`

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty its giving me a castError: cast to embedded failed for value (then value of newNot). lead me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356267/mongooseerror-cast-to-embedded-failed-for-value but the workaround to the mongoose bug in that answer didn't work for me didn't work for me

Comment: can you post the undate query here? 
how you are sending `notifyUser._id` ?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty thanks for the help man, but i just found the error. its the silliest thing you would never suspect. look at the schema, the onObject part of the notifications array. i absent-mindedly used the word "type" as a key in the onObject object. this made mongoose consider the onObject property to be a String. that's the reason for the error. now that i fixed it, all methods work (including yours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the changes to the user weren't being saved because of a mistake i made in the schema, i absent-mindedly used the word "type" as a key in the onObject object. here:

```
onObject: {
        type: String, //post, comment, answer
        id: String //id. but not as mongoose object because it is not necessary in this case.
    }
```

this made mongoose think that onObject was a string. when in fact i meant for it to be an object. renaming the key type to something else solved the problem.

```
onObject: { //not necessary if type (above) is 4
        objectType: String, //post, comment, answer
        id: String //id. but not as mongoose object because it is not necessary in this case.
    },
```

I was unable to find the issue before because i wasn't catching the error, i replaced:

```
notifyUser.save();
```

which was failing silently, with:

```
notifyUser.save(function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

(using findByIdAndUpdate also failed silently, while using update and $push gave an unclear error message).

I'm not deleting the question because in case somebody runs into a similar issue, this could help